# Unable to access camera in Pip(Picture-in-Picture) like whatsapp in iOS(swift)

Tags: ios, swift, whatsapp, picture-in-picture, videocall

I am trying to implement video call in iOS app. So when user goes to background i need to show camera in picture in picture(pip) mode.

When i go to background mode, pip is getting enabled and i can see the camera roll but the camera gets freezed

Facing this error: videoDeviceNotAvailableWithMultipleForegroundApps

Referred: [https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/adopting_picture_in_picture_for_video_calls?changes=la](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private var pictureInPictureController: AVPictureInPictureController!
    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    let pipVideoCallViewController = AVPictureInPictureVideoCallViewController()
    var pipContentSource: AVPictureInPictureController.ContentSource!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(sessionWasInterrupted), name: .AVCaptureSessionWasInterrupted, object: captureSession)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(sessionInterruptionEnded), name: .AVCaptureSessionInterruptionEnded, object: captureSession)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(sessionRuntimeError), name: .AVCaptureSessionRuntimeError, object: captureSession)

        try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        
        let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices().filter{ $0.hasMediaType(AVMediaType.video) && $0.position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.back }
        if let captureDevice = devices.first {
            try? captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice))
            captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo
            
            captureSession.beginConfiguration()
            if captureSession.isMultitaskingCameraAccessSupported {
                // Enable use of the camera in multitasking modes.
                captureSession.isMultitaskingCameraAccessEnabled = true
            }
            captureSession.commitConfiguration()
            
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                self.captureSession.startRunning()
            }
            
            let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
            previewLayer.bounds = view.bounds
            previewLayer.position = CGPointMake(view.bounds.midX, view.bounds.midY)
            previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
            let cameraPreview = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, view.bounds.size.width, view.bounds.size.height))
            cameraPreview.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
            view.addSubview(cameraPreview)
            
            if AVPictureInPictureController.isPictureInPictureSupported() {
                pipVideoCallViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 640, height: 480)
                pipVideoCallViewController.view.addSubview(cameraPreview)
                
                pipContentSource = AVPictureInPictureController.ContentSource(
                    activeVideoCallSourceView: view,
                    contentViewController: pipVideoCallViewController)
                
                pictureInPictureController = AVPictureInPictureController(contentSource: pipContentSource)
                pictureInPictureController.canStartPictureInPictureAutomaticallyFromInline = true
                pictureInPictureController.startPictureInPicture()
            }
        }
        
        do {
            let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
            try audioSession.setCategory(.playback)
            try audioSession.setMode(.moviePlayback)
            try audioSession.setActive(true)
        } catch let e {
            print(e.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    @objc func sessionWasInterrupted(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let userInfoValue = notification.userInfo?[AVCaptureSessionInterruptionReasonKey] as AnyObject?,
           let reasonIntegerValue = userInfoValue.integerValue,
           let reason = AVCaptureSession.InterruptionReason(rawValue: reasonIntegerValue) {
            
            switch reason {
            case .videoDeviceNotAvailableInBackground:
                print("videoDeviceNotAvailableInBackground")
            case .audioDeviceInUseByAnotherClient, .videoDeviceInUseByAnotherClient:
                print("audioDeviceInUseByAnotherClient")
            case .videoDeviceNotAvailableWithMultipleForegroundApps:
                print("videoDeviceNotAvailableWithMultipleForegroundApps")
            case .videoDeviceNotAvailableDueToSystemPressure:
                print("videoDeviceNotAvailableDueToSystemPressure")
                break
            @unknown default:
                break
            }
            
        }
    }

    
    @objc func sessionInterruptionEnded(_ notification: NSNotification) {
        print(notification)
    }
    
    @objc func sessionRuntimeError(_ notification: NSNotification) {
        print(notification)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Could you find a solution?

Comment: Nope. Still not. Kindly help me if you find the solution @ajw

Comment: Add the entitlement (com.apple.developer.avfoundation.multitasking-camera-access) and request access to the multitasking camera - https://developer.apple.com/contact/request/multitasking-camera-access/ (You should have Account holder permission for this)